# How to stop modal with close button in NSWindowController?

Tags: objective-c, macos, modal-dialog, nswindowcontroller, nspanel

I want to stop modal when the user clicks the red close button in NSWindowController.

In the NSWindowController, there are "OK" and "Cancel" buttons.

```
- (IBAction)okButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    [NSApp stopModalWithCode:NSOKButton];
    [self.window close];
}

- (IBAction)cancelButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    [NSApp stopModalWithCode:NSCancelButton];
    [self.window close];
}
```

And when I click the red close button, the window will close and the modal doesn't stop.
I've found the **windowWillClose:** function.

```
- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ([NSApp modalWindow] == self.window)
        [NSApp stopModal];
}
```

However,

```
if ([NSApp runModalForWindow:myWindowController.window] != NSOKButton)
    return;
```

Even if I click the OK button, **windowWillClose:** function is called and **runModalForWindow:** function always returns NSCancelButton.

I can add the member variable into **myWindowController** as the result of the modal.

But I think that there'll be another generic way to resolve this problem.

I want to take an easy way.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's a little bit late, but I just found this question in attempt to find an answer for myself. And that's what is said in the official docs: there is `- (BOOL)windowShouldClose:(id)sender` event handler which is not called when you close the window by [window close]. It is only called when you use red close button or [window performClose:] selector. So the solution is to implement `windowShouldClose:` instead of `windowWillClose:` in your NSWindowController subclass.

Answer (score 3):

You can try like this

```
- (IBAction)okButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    [NSApp stopModalWithCode:NSOKButton];
    [NSApp endSheet:self.window];
}

- (IBAction)cancelButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    [NSApp stopModalWithCode:NSCancelButton];
    [NSApp endSheet:self.window];
}
```

Comment: I want to stop modal when the user clicks the red close button in NSWindowController.

Comment: You can try this method  `- (NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *)sender {
}`  in Appdelegate

Answer (score 2):

According to 
[NSapplication Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/endSheet:)
the endSheet: methods on NSApplication will be deprecated in 10.10 (Mavericks).  Apple recommends using the NSWindow beginSheet: and endSheet: methods so if you're trying to dismiss your NSWindowController from within your NSWindowController subclass you should use this code snippet

```
[self.window.sheetParent endSheet:self.window];
```

It uses NSWindow's ***sheetParent*** property to call ***endSheet:*** and passes your subclass' window as the argument.  You can also use NSWindow's endSheet: returnCode: if you wish to specify the return code.  Tested on OSX 10.9 / XCode 6.1.1